# Why does /usr/share/dict/words contain "manbird" on OSX?

Tags: macos

What is the source of this file on OSX specifically? And why would it contain "manbird" which is clearly not a word: https://uglyamericans.fandom.com/wiki/Manbird

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286787/who-or-what-compiled-usr-share-dict-words?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the word was in at least [one dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Manbird).

But it seems strange that they'd include that and not [dogcow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogcow).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a wrong interpretation of [Birdperson](https://rickandmorty.fandom.com/wiki/Birdperson).